# Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null" in a dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a dom-repeat where I want to insert an image with a src based on function. This time using the index in the function doesn't solve the issue and now I'm stuck. Polymer version is 1.8.0
I tried so far different ways, last one is:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{top.top}}" as="item">
       <img id="testid" src="{{imgurl}}">
</template>

<script>
   Polymer({
     is: 'test',

  ready: function() {
// Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('testid').src = this.imgurl;
 this.$.testid.src = this.imgurl;
  } ,

properties: {
    top: {
        type: Array,
        value: function() { return []; }
    },

    imgurl: {
        type: String,
        notify: true,
        reflectToAttribute: true,
        computed: 'changeimg(score, oldscore)'  
        }
  },

  changeimg: function(score, oldscore) {

      if( score>oldscore ){url = "images/reddown.png";}
      else if(score<oldscore){url ="images/greenup.png";}
      else {url = "images/blueorizontal.png";}
      return url;
  },

....


  });
 </script>
```

Always the result is the same... 
Any ideea? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing src$ instead of src ?

Comment: you mean:     <img id="testid" src$="{{imgurl}}"> ? then, yes, I tried...

Comment: Could you clarify what the contents of your top array looks like and what you are trying to accomplish. There are several issues with your code that I don't think will achieve what you actually want.

Comment: yes, sure:  <iron-ajax auto url="http://localhost:8808/datal2/" handle-as="json" last-response="{{top}}"></iron-ajax>  - from  this json I take also the score and oldscore values and based on them I want to display a red or a green arrow.  "top": [{
  "l2": "NAME NAME",
  "score": 12680,
  "block": "department",
  "oldscore": 13680
 }

Answer (score 1):

The `this.$` only works for elements that are part of your element when it is first created. When using `dom-repeat` or `dom-if` this won't be the case, so `this.$.testid` doesn't exist, resulting in the error you are seeing.

Also your other attempt using `querySelector` will only return one img element, but when rendered you will have one img element for each of your score entries.

The computed property `imgurl` won't help you either, because your element only has one imgurl property which would be always the same, even with score values provided, no matter what score entry is displayed.

The way to solve your problem is to use a [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed) which calculates the right img src for each of the displayed scores.

```
<img src="[[changeimg(item.score, item.oldscore)]]">
```

Comment: Yes! this solved my problem. I guess I need to start learning some more ... (actually web-development was something quite new to me ). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line `computed: 'changeimg(score, oldscore)'`.

You haven't defined `score` and `oldscore`. This is computed value not observer.

So, defining those will solve the problem.